# Evaluate : $\int\frac{1}{\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta}\, d\theta$

Tags: indefinite-integrals

I would like to evaluate the following indefinite integral:

> $$\int\frac{1}{\sin^4\theta+\cos^4\theta}\, d\theta$$

Comment: $d\theta{}{}{}{}$

Comment: It can be reduced to $\int\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2} (\sin 2 \theta)^2 } d\theta$. A possible way is then to expand the integrand into a series and integrate term by term... but is it a good solution ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I think you forgot to square $\sin 2\theta$.

Comment: @S.C.B. You are right. Thank you. I have corrected it.

Comment: Why the close votes for "off topic" everybody? This is quite clearly a mathematics question. Sure, it could be worded better but please take into consideration that this is R.P's first post.

To R.P: Please have a read of this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @Trogdor The link in your comment answers the (rhetorical?) question in it.

Comment: @Trogdor : "Off-topic" is used as a catch-all when other things don't fit.  They shouldn't do that, but they do. The question was phrased in language like that suitable for assigning homework, and that is frowned on here.  People who close things for that reason ought to explain that here in comments, but usually don't.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $$\left ( \sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta \right )^2 = \sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta + 2 \sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta  $$

By re-arranging and using double angle formulas, we have

$$\sin^4 \theta + \cos^4 \theta = 1-\frac{1}{2}\sin^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )$$

So our integrand is

$$\frac{2}{2-\sin^2 \left (2\theta \right )}$$

Using the fact that $\sin^2 x = 1- \cos ^2 x$, we have

$$\frac{2}{1+\cos^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )}$$

Divide the numerator and denominator by $\cos ^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )$

$$\frac{2 \sec ^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )}{\sec ^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )+1}$$

Now use the fact that $\sec ^2 x = 1+ \tan ^2 x$ to get

$$\frac{2 \sec ^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )}{2 + \tan^2 \left ( 2\theta \right )}$$

From here, using the substitution $u=\tan \left ( 2\theta \right )$, this becomes

$$\int \frac{du}{2+u^2}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1} \left ( \frac{u}{\sqrt{2}} \right )+C $$

And finally putting it back in terms of $\theta$, this becomes

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \tan^{-1} \left ( \frac{\tan \left ( 2\theta \right )}{\sqrt{2}} \right )+C $$

Answer (score 2):

Starting with S.C.B.'s reduction of the integral to
$$
\int \frac{t^2+1}{t^4+1} \, dt,
$$
let's do some algebra:
\begin{align}
t^4 + 1 & = (t^4 + 2t^2 + 1) - (t\sqrt 2)^2 \\[10pt]
& = (t^2+1)^2 -(t \sqrt 2)^2  & & (\text{a difference of two squares}) \\[10pt]
& = \Big((t^2+1) - (t\sqrt 2)\Big) \Big((t^2+1) + (t\sqrt 2)\Big).
\end{align}
Then use partial fractions to get
$$
\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+1} = \frac{At+B}{t^2 -t\sqrt 2 + 1} + \frac{Ct+B}{t^2 + t\sqrt 2 + 1}.
$$
Letting $u = t^2 -t\sqrt 2 + 1$ you have $du = (2t -\sqrt 2)\,dt$.

So you have $At+B = \frac A 2 \left( (2t - \sqrt 2) + \left( \sqrt2 + \frac{2B} A \right) \right)$.

Use the $u$ substitution to deal with $(2t-\sqrt2)\,dt$.  Next you have
$$
\int \frac{\text{constant}\cdot dt}{t^2 - t\sqrt2 + 1}.
$$
So
$$
\overbrace{t^2 - t\sqrt 2 + 1 = \left(t - \frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \right)^2 + \frac 1 2}^\text{completing the square} = \frac 1 2 \left( (t\sqrt 2 - 1)^2 + 1 \right)
$$
Let $w = t\sqrt 2 - 1$ so that $\dfrac{dw}{\sqrt 2} = dt$ so you get $\displaystyle \int \frac{dw}{1+w^2}$ and you get an arctangent.

Comment: $$\int\frac{1+x^2}{1+x^4}dx=\int\frac{\frac1{x^2}+1}{\frac1{x^2}+x^2} dx$$


Now the idea is to express the denominator as a polynomial of $\int \left(\frac1{x^2}+1 \right)dx =x-\frac1x=u\text{(say)}$

 $$\text{The denominator =}\frac1{x^2}+x^2=\left(x-\frac1x\right)^2+2=u^2+2$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\int \frac{1}{\sin^4t + \cos^4t} dt = \int \frac{1}{\sin^4(t)+\cos^4(t)}\frac{\sec^4(t)}{\sec^4(t)} dt = \int \frac{\sec^2(t)(1+\tan^2(t))}{\tan^4(t)+1} dt = $$
(letting $u = \tan(t), du = \sec^2(t)$)
$$\int \frac{1+u^2}{1+u^4} du = \int \frac{1+u^2}{(u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1)(u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1)} du = $$$$\frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{u^2-\sqrt{2}u+1} + \frac{1}{u^2+\sqrt{2}u+1}du = \frac{1}{2}\int\frac{1}{(u-\sqrt{2}/2)^2+\frac{1}{2}} + \frac{1}{(u+\sqrt{2}/2)^2+\frac{1}{2}} du=$$
(noting that $\int \frac{1}{(x-a)^2+b^2}dx = \frac{1}{b}\tan^{-1}(\frac{x-a}{b})$)
$$ = \frac{1}{2}(\sqrt{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{u-\sqrt{2}/2}{\sqrt{2}/2})+\sqrt{2}\tan^{-1}(\frac{u+\sqrt{2}/2}{\sqrt{2}/2}))  +C = $$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2}u-1) + \tan^{-1}(\sqrt{2}u+1))+C$$
Substitute $u = \tan(t)$ into this to get the final answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let $$I = \int\frac{1}{\sin^4 \theta+\cos^4 \theta}d\theta = \int\frac{\sin^2 \theta +\cos^2 \theta}{\sin^2 \theta \cos^2 \theta (\tan^2 \theta +\cot^2 \theta)}d\theta$$

So $$I = \int\frac{\sec^2 \theta +\csc^2 \theta}{\tan^2 \theta +\cot^2 \theta }d\theta = \int\frac{\sec^2 \theta+\csc^2 \theta}{(\tan \theta-\cot \theta)^2+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2}d\theta$$

Now put $(\tan \theta -\cot \theta) = t\;,$ Then $(\sec^2 \theta +\csc^2 \theta)d\theta = dt$

So $$I = \int\frac{1}{t^2+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)^2}dt = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\mathcal{C}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\tan \theta-\cot \theta }{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$